# OrderBy is not working with relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 8 I have code:

```
$ratings = user_quiz::where('quiz_id',$id)->orderBy('correct', 'desc')->get();
```

Then in blade:

```
@foreach ($ratings as $rating)
<tr>
  <td>{{$rating->user->name}}</td> 
  <td>{{$rating->quiz_id}}</td> 
  <td>{{$rating->correct}}</td>                                         
</tr>
@endforeach
```

In user_quiz model:

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

As a result, the rating is not ordered by `correct` column.
But, when I remove line

```
<td>{{$rating->user->name}}</td>
```

then it works fine.

What is the problem in your opinion

Comment: Lazy calls is changing the collections order?

Comment: Try `$ratings = user_quiz::where('quiz_id',$id)->with('user')->orderBy('correct', 'desc')->get();`

Comment: this solution is not working as well. The same problem remains